# Filter product collection by group product child count.

Tags: grouped-products

I need to be able to filter a product collection for grouped products that is not the issue i also need to filter the collection by grouped products that have a specific number of child products.

Any help would be appreciated been wrapping my brain arround this one today.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

i know about the relationship just trying to filter the relationship was the problem just decided on this approach.

```
public function hasChildCount($count, $catid)
        {
            $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
                $countProducts = count($associatedProducts);
                if(($count == 5 &&  $count >= $countProducts ))
                {
                    $ids[] = $product->getId();
                }elseif($count == $countProducts)
                {
                    $ids[] = $product->getId();
                }
                // Do something with $associatedProducts
            }

            return $ids;
        }
```

and then in the actual attribute to filter

```
 array('entity_id'=>array('in',$idsIn ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento is save the relation between `grouped product ant it related child products` at database table  `catalog_product_link`.

In this table,there relation is build with field( `link_type_id=3`)

Now,if i add new column which is add count of child product then it would properly work